# How to simplify this LINQ WHERE query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to select several rows from a table but would like the selection to stop if the first where clause comes back with results. Basically if there are results with language then I don't need to query for DevLanguage or FallbackLanguage, is this possible in a single query with || operator or with some other LINQ magic?

> ```
>         var languageStrings = _presentationContext.LocalizationStrings
>             .Where(x => x.Namespace.Namespace == @namespace &&
>                         x.Namespace.Language == language);
>
>         var devStrings = _presentationContext.LocalizationStrings
>             .Where(x => x.Namespace.Namespace == @namespace &&
>                         x.Namespace.Language == Constants.DevLanguage);
>
>         var fallbackStrings = _presentationContext.LocalizationStrings
>             .Where(x => x.Namespace.Namespace == @namespace &&
>                         x.Namespace.Language == Constants.FallbackLanguage);
>
>         var localizationStrings = languageStrings.Any() ? languageStrings : devStrings.Any() ? devStrings : fallbackStrings.Any() ? fallbackStrings
> ```

Comment: Sure give it a try

Comment: as far as simplification, I'd say this code is pretty clean and legible as is.  If you want to optimize it to not have potentially 3 database trips, that could be another question

Comment: @Jonesopolis That would pretty much be my goal, to check for these three things in a single query but stop if I found results with the first. Like some sort of FirstOrDefault but with a group.

Comment: Looks practically impossible to me since there is no such LINQ operator (nether SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the common part of these queries into a separate query.

```
var query = _presentationContext.LocalizationStrings.Where(x => x.Namespace.Namespace == @namespace);

var languageStrings = query.Where(x => x.Namespace.Language == language);
var devStrings = query.Where(x => x.Namespace.Language == Constants.DevLanguage);
var fallbackStrings = query.Where(x => x.Namespace.Language == Constants.FallbackLanguage);
```

The SQL is generated the same.

Answer (score 0):

While there are probably more downsides to the code below than I know of, it's a one-liner (if you ignore the temp variable declaration) and only executes the LINQ queries if the previous one failed to return any results.

```cs
IEnumerable<dynamic> temp;
var localizationStrings =
        (temp = _presentationContext.LocalizationStrings.Where(x => 
                    x.Namespace.Namespace == @namespace && 
                    x.Namespace.Language == language)).Any() ? temp :
        (temp = _presentationContext.LocalizationStrings.Where(x => 
                    x.Namespace.Namespace == @namespace &&
                    x.Namespace.Language == Constants.DevLanguage)).Any() ? temp :
        (temp = _presentationContext.LocalizationStrings.Where(x =>
                    x.Namespace.Namespace == @namespace &&
                    x.Namespace.Language == Constants.FallbackLanguage)).Any() ? temp :
        Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

One reason why I would either pick your original code or search for a different method is because assigning values in a chain like this is not performance friendly.